# What is the last line in my port configurator?

Tags: port-forwarding

Hi I wanted to forward some ports for gaming. What should I enter in the last line? The same as above? What is this line?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you’d enter the same as the “von Port” field, yes.

The “an Port” field indicates where on the (internal) target machine the traffic should be directed. Unless you know what you’re doing, you’d usually use the same port/range both externally and internally.

Answer (score 0):

#### What is this line?

"an Port" is the port you are forwarding **To**.

> Tragen Sie unter "an Port" die erste Portnummer ein, auf der der Serverdienst bzw. die Internetanwendung Verbindungen entgegen nimmt.

Translation:

> Enter the number of the first port used by the server service or Internet application to accept connections in the "to Port" field.

Source [Portfreigaben in FRITZ!Box einrichten](http://avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-6360-cable/wissensdatenbank/publication/show/893_Statische-Portfreigaben-einrichten/)

Note the instructions [here](http://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7330/knowledge-base/publication/show/893_Configuring-static-port-sharing/) (although for a FRITZ!Box 7330) are in English and appear to be identical.